# In xcode 3.2, does the iPhone simulator approximate CPU speed?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

I just upgraded to Snow Leopard and have noticed that my NSLog() calls (among other things) in the iPhone simulator are taking quite a long time, way longer than they used to.  Did Apple update the simulator to better approximate the iPhone's CPU speed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds unlikely - is anything else slower, other than NSLog()? How are you measuring "slowness"?

Its far more likely that some internal threading or synchronization issue in the tools has changed from Xcode 3.1 to 3.2, resulting in the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: The NSLog() calls in particular are much, much slower.

Answer (score 0):

No.  And I say that because my apps on the iPhone still run much slower than my apps in the Simulator.